# 10.1 wxga tablet is large screen why?

Tags: android, size, screen

why the 10.1" WXGA tablet is considered as large screen not xlarge screen although in the android development tuto they added that devices with screen size of 7" and more are considered as xlarge so why it's considered as large screen and not xlarge screen which devices are the xlarge screens..?thanks.

Comment: android used to go purely by total pixels and completely ignored physical screen size. e.g. a Nexus 10 has a 10.x" screen and 2560x1440 pixels. an ipad 2 also has a 10" screen but is only 1024x768. e.g. the exact same physical screen size, but the Nexus has effectively the same pixel realestate as **4** ipads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some manufacturers tweak the sdk. For ex Samsung galaxy note has 5 inch , ideally should pick Res from large folder but it picks frm normal folder.